# Fullscreen activity is hiding listview contents when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

when the keyboards pops up the first couple of rows in my listview cant be viewed, I really dont want to have to revert to non fullscreen in one activity of my app because of this and i'm sure others wouldn't - so anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize":`

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is already in the manifest for that particualr activity, also have tried adjustPan many times!